# How do I float some text and an image at the top of the page?

Tags: css

It should be very simple, but I am, so it's not ...

The first thing on the page, right after `<body>`, I want a sort of banner, containing some text which is left aligned, and an image which is right aligned. It should occupy te full width of the page.

Can you do that without knowing the width og the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, put image in one div, and text in another, define "float: right" property for the div with the image, and "float: left" for div with the text in CSS

```
<div class="div1"><img src=...></div>
<div class="div2">text</div>

<style type="text/css">
.div1 {
  float: right;
}

.div2 {
  float: left;
}
</style>
```

Comment: +1 to everyone and the answer to the one who answered first. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="banner">
<div style="float: left; width: 50%;">
left - just put your text here
</div>
<div style="float: right; width: 50%;">
right - just put your image here
</div>
</div>
```

You may also want to use a clearfix (google it) technique to ensure the banner div always has height no matter how big the image is.

Comment: +1 to everyone and the answer to the one who answered first. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/KaHjd/1/

I've assumed that you want the image right aligned as well.

```
#header {
    overflow:auto;
}

#branding {
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #00AA00;
}

#logo {
    float:right;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #aa0000;
    overflow:auto;
}

#logo img {
    float:right;
} 

<div id='header'>
    <div id='branding'>
        some text
    </div>
    <div id='logo'>
        <img src='http://placekitten.com/200/100'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 to everyone and the answer to the one who answered first. Thanks, all.

Answer (score 1):

Of course we can. But your image must be small enough in order for your text not to overflow the banner.

HTML

```
<div class="banner">
    <span>Text goes here</span>
    <img src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.banner { overflow: hidden; width: 100%; }
.banner span { float: left; }
.banner img { float: right; }
```

Comment: +1 to everyone and the answer to the one who answered first. Thanks, all.