# How do I give the same background color to all elements in a container?

Tags: css

Thanks for the very quick replies to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6314392/how-to-do-this-in-css).

"The first thing on the page, right after , I want a sort of banner, containing some text which is left aligned, and an image which is right aligned. It should occupy te full width of the page."

I forgot to mention that I would like the entire "banner" to have the same background colo(u)r. The text, the image and everything in between.

Comment: please show what you have, and what's not working

Comment: You just need to assign a bg to the container and remove the bg from the child elements. Also, these kinds of updates should be posted on the original questions and not in a new one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/AQ4kb/)?

## HTML

```
<div class="divwrap">
    <div class="div1">text</div>
    <div class="div2"><img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3170/2724062433_68f2af7af7_m.jpg"></div>
    <div class="divclear"></div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.divwrap
{
    background-color: #CCC;
}
.div1
{
    float: left;
}
.div2
{
    float: right;
}
.div2 img
{
    display: block;
}
.divclear
{
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: +1 and the answer. That's exactly it - an enclosing div, wrapped around the others. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
  <div style="height:100px;width:100%;background:url(yourimage.png);background-position:right;">Yourtext</div>
```

Comment: do I really need an image? or are you just trying to show me a more advance technique?

Answer (score 2):

```
.banner{ color:blue;
         background-color:blue;
         background:url(yourimage.png);
         background-position:right;
         width:100%
       }
```

in addition, you can have create a new class so that the div for for banner can inherit the properties, this way you can seperate the div for the image and text

Comment: do I really need an image? or are you just trying to show me a more advance technique?